# Getting rid of extra spacing for embedded media?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm currently working on a mosaic web layout of embedded media (twitter, instagram, etc...).

It has 3 columns, which are populated with divs set to display: none; using PHP and MYSQL.

Once the divs have been populated, I'm using a Javascript function showPost(); to display the content. When the users scroll to the bottom of the page, showPost(); is called again to unhide the next divs.

I'm running into a spacing problem with embedded media and I can't manage to find a way around it.

I've created a JSFiddle of the problem.

I've tried everything, padding, margin, line-height, all set to zero.

I can't figure out where this extra spacing is coming from? Any help would be much appreciated.

[Click Here for JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4bL9teh1/3/)

```
#column{
    position: absolute;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 500px;
    line-height: 0;
}
#div01{
    position: relative;
    display: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 0;
    background-color: blue;
}
#div02{ 
    position: relative;
    display: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0; 
    line-height: 0;
    background-color: blue;
}
#div03{ 
    position: relative;
    display: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0; 
    line-height: 0;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: Where exactly is the unwanted spacing?

Comment: It's right below each embedded media. I'm trying to get the embeded media to stack flush to each other, without a new line space between them.

Comment: there's something weird going on with  the frame, i just set margin -10px, http://jsfiddle.net/4bL9teh1/6/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is caused by the twitter widget adding an iframe with the margin set in the html element (`<iframe stlye="margin-top:...`). You can get around this with a bit of javascript to check iframes when they are added and remove their margins.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    showPost();

    $('body').on('DOMNodeInserted', 'iframe', function () {
        $('iframe.twitter-tweet').css({
             'margin-top': '0',
             'margin-bottom': '0'
        });
    });
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4bL9teh1/5/)

Comment: Thanks! I don't think I would've been able to figure that out on my own, I spent about 8 hours on and off trying to get rid of that.

Comment: Try yakutsa's answer too. It's a much simpler solution. I had tried a CSS solution before resorting to JS, but for some reason it didn't work. yakutsa's does though.

Answer (score 1):

Twitter widget iframe automatically creates a `margin: 10px 0px;` for the content. To remove this code, simply adding `iframe {margin: 0 !important}` to your css file would be enough.

[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4bL9teh1/4/)

```
#column{
    position: absolute;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 500px;
    line-height: 0;
}
#div01{
    position: relative;
    display: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 0;
    background-color: blue;
}
#div02{ 
    position: relative;
    display: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0; 
    line-height: 0;
    background-color: blue;
}
#div03{ 
    position: relative;
    display: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0; 
    line-height: 0;
    background-color: blue;
}
iframe{margin:0 !important;}
```